# Xerces DomParser, get name of the child node

Tags: c++, xerces, domparser

I'm trying to get a function that returns the name of the first child node of a parent node.

```
std::string  XmlParser::XmlDomDocument::getChildNodeName(const char* parentTag, int parentIndex){

    XMLCh* temp = XMLString::transcode(parentTag);
    DOMNodeList* list = m_doc->getElementsByTagName(temp);
    XMLString::release(&temp);

    DOMNode *parentnode = dynamic_cast<DOMNode*>(list->item(parentIndex));
    DOMNode *childnode= parentnode->getFirstChild();

    char* temp2 = XMLString::transcode(childnode->getNodeName());
    string value = temp2;
    XMLString::release(&temp2);

    return value;
}
```

For example return "node b" in the case of the following XML:

```
<node a>"AAA"</node a>
<node b>"BBB"</node b>
```

Don't know what's went wrong, I can launch the function but it returns the string "#text" instead of the node name.

I am using the Xerces DomParser with C++.